# Passing data from viewmodel to viewmodel and use it .Net maui

Tags: c#, .net, maui

How to use viewmodel to get data and draw graphic? Can I send data from  mainpageviewmodel to use on graphicviewmodel and show on graphicpage?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<CollectionView
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding graphiclist}"
            SelectionMode="None">

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:GRAPHICModel">
            <Grid Padding="0">
                <Frame HeightRequest="100">
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}, Path=DrawGRAPHCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Grid Padding="0">
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" Text="{Binding GraphicNamae}" />
                        
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

**mainpageviewmodel.cs**

```
public partial class MainpageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
        public ObservableCollection<GRAPHICModel> graphiclist { get; set; }
        public MainpageViewModel()
        {
            graphiclist = new ObservableCollection<GRAPHICModel>
            {
                new GRAPHICModel { GraphicName= "Name1", Path = "somecoordinate" },
                new GRAPHICModel { GraphicName= "Name2", Path = "somecoordinate" },
                new GRAPHICModel { GraphicName= "Name3", Path = "somecoordinate" },
                new GRAPHICModel { GraphicName= "Name4", Path = "somecoordinate" }
            };
        }

    [ICommand]
    async Task DrawGRAPHCommand(GRAPHICModel glist)
    {
       
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(DrawPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["GRAPHICModel"] = glist
        });
    }
}
```

**graphicpage.xaml**

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Graphiclist.GraphicName}" />
    <FlexLayout
        AlignItems="Center"
        Direction="Column"
        JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly">

        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <GraphicsView
                Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
                HeightRequest="1000"
                WidthRequest="1000" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </FlexLayout>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

**graphicviewmodel.cs**

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Graphiclist), "GRAPHICModel")]

public partial class GraphicViewModel : ObservableObject, IDrawable
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    GRAPHICModel graphiclist;

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        something.load(graphiclist.Path)
         canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
            canvas.StrokeSize = 4;
            canvas.DrawPath();
    }
}
```

After tap, I cannot get **graphiclist.path** for **canvas.DrawPath(-somepoint-);**  after tap

but can show `<Label Text="{Binding Graphiclist.GraphicName}" />`

Comment: From your code `Path` seems to be a string. Is that correct?

Comment: Ah yes ,It's string website  but I don't need to show link. It not matter what is path but I can not use graphiclist.Path in draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect),I use shell app

Comment: What does _can not use graphiclist.Path_ means? Is `Path` null? If so, probaby `Draw` is called before `graphiclist` is initialized.

Comment: Yes graphiclist.Path It's null in `Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)` ,Not null when show label. I debug it. the problem is when  call Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)

Comment: Another couple of questions: in `Draw` method is `Path` the only null property or is the entire object `graphiclist` null?
And where do you set the `Country` property?

Comment: Sorry I mistake Country  change to GraphicName

Comment: Ok, and about the other question? When `Draw` is called is `graphicslist` null?

Comment: I think  after call constructor  public GraphicViewModel (){}

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: what's the value of `graphicslist` during the execution of `Draw`? Is it null or not?

Comment: In grapicllist keep filename,and path for webesite ,So <Label Text="{Binding Graphiclist.GraphicName}" /> can show filename  on graphicpage.xaml but can not get Graphiclist.path in Draw() in graphicviewmodel.cs

Comment: I got it, but what I want to know is whether inside the Draw method graphiclist is not initialized yet. Can you put a breakpoint inside Draw body and check if graphiclist is null?

Comment: Draw() call after  <Label Text="{Binding Graphiclist.GraphicName}" /> show

Comment: Ok, sorry to insist but this could help me to understand your problem and you're not answering explicitly to my question. What's the value of `graphiclist` when the method `Draw` is called? You could simply set a breakpoint inside `Draw` body and check it.

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM for communication between View Models common practice is to use Mediator Design Pattern !! There are a lot articles around it as much as yt videos.

Comment: Actually the author way to pass data is the suggested one if you're using Shell. For this case I wouldn't suggest a pattern change.